# Is it safe to use nickel-plated flatware?

Tags: environmental-health

Some people have claimed that nickel is unsafe to use in flatware (i.e. cutlery) - [Example 1](http://www.finishing.com/208/58.shtml), [Example 2](http://www.howtodothings.com/family-relationships/how-to-choose-a-flatware-set).

Indeed, nickel is a carcinogen ([Ref 1](http://www.lenntech.com/periodic/elements/ni.htm), [Ref 2](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/full/10.1021/tx700198a)).

Is it safe to use nickel-plated flatware?

Comment: Has anyone claimed it is dangerous? We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people, rather than just speculation.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made.

Comment: Agreed, please show us some that someone is actually claiming that as this looks like mere speculation.

Comment: Also nickel silver (usually used on flatware) is different than pure nickel. The concern regarding toxicity is mainly aimed towards industrial workers that are exposed to nickel every day.

Comment: Some people are allergic to nickel. http://www.mayoclinic.com/health/nickel-allergy/DS00826

Comment: @Nostrum: Aren't you exposed to cutlery every day? :) But well - we're eating *with* flatware, not eating *the* flatware.

Comment: Here's a claim on a blog which reads "Nickel is not poisonous in small quantities but it can cause an allergic reaction. **People with nickel allergies should avoid cooking with stainless steel cookware**."  _Source:_  http://eartheasy.com/blog/2009/01/healthy-cookware/  There's also an article entitled "**Stainless steel cookware as a significant source of nickel, chromium, and iron**" that mentions "nickel sensitive patients" on this Government web site:  http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1514841

Comment: You might like [Bioavailability, intracellular mobilization of nickel, and HIF-1{alpha} activation in human lung epithelial cells exposed to metallic nickel and nickel oxide nanoparticles](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21828359) which in the abstract says "metallic Ni nanoparticles, in contrast to micron-sized Ni particles, activate a toxicity pathway characteristic of carcinogenic Ni compounds". So now it's just a matter of, does flatware release nickel nanoparticles and/or micron-sized nickel compound particles?

Comment: I started researching this, but the question is still unclear. Some people are talking about the Nickel/Coppter undercoat of silver-plating, in which case you aren't exposed unless the silver-plating is worn away. Some people are talking about stainless steel - some alloys contain some nickel content.